# Trying to create a nested conditional but it's skipping all my other options

Tags: python, nested, conditional-statements

For my Python course I'm writing a chatbot that asks the user about their credit score. I am trying to have this part of code be a nested conditional to meet the requirements for the assignment. However regardless of input from the user it only uses the first 'if' and ignores everything else beneath it. This is the code:

```
#User inputs their credit score 
User_Credit=int(input("Please input your credit score here -->"))

if User_Credit > 600:
  print("You qualify for a Low loan.")
else:
  if User_Credit > 800:
    print("You qualify for a High loan.")
  else:
    print("I am sorry you do not qualify for any loan.")
print()
```

I am not sure where I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first if statement you are checking if the credit is greater than 600, but you also need to make sure it's less than 800. Try this:

```
if User_Credit > 600 and User_Credit < 800:
```

also, your second conditional should probably be `>=` instead of `>`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to move the second conditional inside "if" statement, not "else". Otherwise the way if statement works is as soon as "if" condition evaluates to True, everything else is not checked.

```
#User inputs their credit score 
User_Credit=int(input("Please input your credit score here -->"))

if User_Credit > 600:
    if User_Credit > 800:
        print("You qualify for a High loan.")
    else:
        print("You qualify for a Low loan.")   
else:
  print("I am sorry you do not qualify for any loan.")
print()
```

But you might as well think about using compound conditionals instead of nested as in the other answer, because "flat is better than nested".

Answer (score 0):

Your `if User_Credit > 800` line will never evaluate to `True` since your outer `if` statement would be `True` first for any condition that would match that inner `if` statement.

In this case you should go from highest-to-lowest and instead of using nested `if` statements, `elif` statements are better-suited and intended for these sorts of scenerios. The below should work as you intended it:

```py
#User inputs their credit score 
User_Credit=int(input("Please input your credit score here -->"))

if User_Credit > 800:
    print("You qualify for a High loan.")
elif User_Credit > 600:
    print("You qualify for a Low loan.")
else:
    print("I am sorry you do not qualify for any loan.")
print()
```